# when trying to implement DialogFlowtter in flutter , I get error for .fromFile()

Tags: flutter, dialogflow-es, chatbot

here is my code.

```
class _ChatbotScreenState extends State<ChatbotScreen> {
  DialogFlowtter? dialogFlowtter;
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> messages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    DialogFlowtter.fromFile().then((instance) => dialogFlowtter = instance);  // here
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 .....
```

the error is, The method 'fromFile' isn't defined for the type 'DialogFlowtter'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromFile'.

Added the json file to assets.

I added, the package   'dialog_flowtter: ' and import 'package:dialog_flowtter/dialog_flowtter.dart';

Comment: Is there an error on the import line? Did `flutter pub get` complete with a success and no error? Do you have other class named `DialogFlowtter`?

Comment: flutter pub get is success and no other class named DialogFlowtter too

Comment: What version of `dialog_flowtter` are you using? Also can you show the output of `flutter doctor`?

Comment: Im using dialog_flowtter: ^0.3.3 . 
before I tried without a version too ( dialog_flowtter: ) but still got the error

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 3.20.0-15.0.pre.26, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3155], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 17.5.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.86.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!

Comment: what file do see if you ctrl-click on `DialogFlowtter`? Is it https://github.com/Deimos-Applications/dialog_flowtter/blob/master/lib/src/dialog.dart?

Comment: pskink, yes thats the one Im seeing

Comment: and doesn't it have that [line](https://github.com/Deimos-Applications/dialog_flowtter/blob/master/lib/src/dialog.dart#L148)?

Comment: after the DialogFlowtter. I only see,  DialogFlowtter.kDefaultJsonPath,          DialogFlowtter.kDialogFlowApiVersion,       DialogFlowtter.kDialogFlowUrl,                DialogFlowtter.getClient()

Comment: pskink, no it doesnt have that line.

Comment: pskink,I copied your whole code from that file and paste it in there. now no errors for fromFile(). but is it okay to delete that previous original code?

Comment: so you have the older version, not `^0.3.3`

Comment: pskink, 
no I have that version. dialog_flowtter: ^0.3.3. got from , https://pub.dev/packages/dialog_flowtter/install. also today I started DialogFlow

Comment: Check the file path, is it showing `-0.3.3`

Comment: I don't know if it's possible that pub cache file corrupt like that, but in that case it's better to delete the package folder from your cache and re-run pub get

Comment: as Dhafin Rayhan said: double check if the full file path contains `-0.3.3`

Comment: Now it solved. I have firebase_ui_oauth which is outdated.  dialog_flowtter >=0.3.0 is incompatible with firebase_ui_oauth ^1.5.0.  also even though I had new version of dialog_flowtter. when u guys told to check the file, it was  0.2.0-nullsafety.0.  I make it  ' firebase_ui_auth: ' with no version nd deleted the dialog_flowtter and again add, flutter pub add dialog_flowtter. now it is working.  now the DialogFlowtter file is just like the pskink showed.

Comment: Thank you very much for Dhafin Rayhan and pskink to help to solve this...